# Changing the values of objects in an array with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

While working on React today, I got stuck somewhere because my basic JavaScript knowledge is not good.

I want to change the value of the "name" property of any object in this array.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-rain-udjcxe?file=/src/App.js

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "jonas" },
  { id: 2, name: "mark" },
  { id: 3, name: "elon" },
];
```

My App.js file

```js
 const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);

  

    const changePerson = (id) => {
    // if I click on the button, the "name" value of the current object will change to anything

  };

  return (
    <main>
      <section>
        {people.map((person) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={person.id}>
              {person.name}
              <button onClick={() => changePerson(person.id)}>change</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by any string expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to create an updated array and set it. Use the callback method `setPeople` to update the array. Try like this:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "jonas" },
  { id: 2, name: "mark" },
  { id: 3, name: "elon" }
];

const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState(data);

  const changePerson = (id) => {
    setPeople((prevPeople) =>
      prevPeople.map((person) =>
        person.id === id ? { ...person, name: "changed" } : person
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <section>
        {people.map((person) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={person.id}>
              {person.name}
              <button onClick={() => changePerson(person.id)}>change</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```